# Error JSF ,He creado mi proyecto en eclipse y me sale este error

Tags: java

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

por favor me podrían decir cual es la solución a este error

Answer (score 1):

Descarga la libreria, prueba este [link](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.faces/jsf-impl/2.2.13).

En el proyecto ve a Build Path > Configure
Pulsa sobre Add External Jar e introduce el fichero que has descargado.
De esta forma habrás añadido la libreria que estas utilizando y podrás utilizar sus funciones en tu código Java.

Comment: Cuidado. OP usa maven.

Comment: @Awes0meM4n no tiene mucho sentido. La idea de maven es que definas las dependencias en el pom y no agregues las dependencias manualmente en el proyecto. Así, cuando commiteas las fuentes del proyecto, te ahorras MBs en el repo puesto que solo indicas qué librerías (y su versión, importante) deben descargarse en tu equipo local para ejecutar el proyecto. Esto es, puedo usar el mismo pom en mi equipo o en el tuyo, al ejecutar maven él detectará si las librerías están en el equipo, de no estar las descarga por ti, de estar continúa con la compilación.

Answer (score 1):

Puesto que en la imagen que publicas se puede ver un pom.xml, la forma correcta de agregar librerías/dependencias en tu proyecto es editando el pom. Abre este archivo y deberías poder encontrar una sección `<dependencies>`. En caso de no existir, créala. Allí deberás agregar las dependencias a JSF que son dos:

1. Definición de JSF
2. Implementación de JSF

Puedes encontrar las dependencias en un sitio como [mvnrepository](http://mvnrepository.com). Aquí te dejo un ejemplo de cómo agregar las dependencias a JSF de las librerías creadas por Oracle para JSF 2 en su versión 2.2.14:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.14</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.14</version>
</dependency>
```

Es posible que luego de agregar tus dependencias debas actualizar el proyecto mediante maven. Para esto, puedes seleccionar tu proyecto y presionar las teclas <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> para forzar el refresco.

Con esto, no necesitas agregar las librerías en el build path de tu proyecto o locuras de ese tipo. Lo bueno de maven (y similares) es que facilitan el trabajo de agregar las dependencias por ti.

Te recomendaría revisar [este sitio](http://chuidiang.org/content/dependencias-con-maven) para que aprendas más sobre el manejo de dependencias con maven.